# Using the routine CSNBOWH on IBM I - MD5

Tags: md5, ibm-midrange, cobol

I am trying to run the routine CSNBOWH on IBM I using COBOL ILE on the pubblic server PUB400. To do the call I used various definition taken from Internet/manuals. This is the last one I used:

```
     01  HASHING-TEXT.                                           
         03 WK-RETURN-CODE          PIC S9(9)  COMP-5 VALUE ZERO.
         03 REASON-CODE             PIC S9(9)  COMP-5 VALUE ZERO.
         03 EXIT-DATA-LENGTH        PIC S9(9)  COMP-5 VALUE 4.   
         03 EXIT-DATA               PIC X(4)   VALUE SPACE.      
         03 RULE-ARRAY-COUNT        PIC S9(9)  COMP-5 VALUE 1.   
         03 RULE-ARRAY              PIC X(8)   VALUE 'MD5'.      
         03 TEXT-LENGTH             PIC S9(9)  COMP-5 VALUE 64.  
         03 TEXT-MESSAGE            PIC X(64)  VALUE SPACE.      
         03 CHAINING-VECTOR-LENGTH  PIC S9(9)  COMP-5 VALUE 128. 
         03 CHAINING-VECTOR         PIC X(128) VALUE SPACE.      
         03 HASH-LENGTH             PIC S9(9)  COMP-5 VALUE 16.  
         03 HASH                    PIC X(16).                   


 CALL  'CSNBOWH'  USING     WK-RETURN-CODE         
                             REASON-CODE           
                             EXIT-DATA-LENGTH      
                             EXIT-DATA             
                             RULE-ARRAY-COUNT      
                             RULE-ARRAY            
                             TEXT-LENGTH           
                             TEXT-MESSAGE          
                             CHAINING-VECTOR-LENGTH
                             CHAINING-VECTOR       
                             HASH-LENGTH           
                             HASH.
```

However I always get the message MCH3401 "The message text for 'MCH3401' follows: 'Cannot resolve to
object CSNBOWH. Type and Subtype X'0201' Authority X'0000'.'"

What you think I don't have the access to this routine?
I try to use also the routines CSNBOWH1 CSNEOWH and CSNEOWH1 with the same result.

I read various manuals on IBM platform and I was thinking that I could use CSNBOWH routine to do hashing. The manual are the following:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=vdiam-one-way-hash-generate-csnbowh-csnbowh1-csneowh-csneowh1
IBM i 7.3 Security Cryptography

However, I am not sure I am in the right direction. If you know an other way in COBOL to get the MD5 will be good to know.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Daniele and welcome to SO with your well done question. Maybe taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is still useful - in any case it will help you to earn the first badge :-)

Comment: I didn't found that in the ibm i manual, which lists functions and a callable service, with a version of 7.1 - do you have a clue which version you use ?

Comment: One possibility is that your working storage field sizes are incorrect.  Just as a test, I'd move the alphanumeric fields to a different 01 level following the 01 HASHING-TEXT and display the before and after results of both 01 level fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need the following installed on your system**

```
5770-SS1 5050 – IBM i Option 35, CCA Cryptographic Service Provider
```

It is not installed by default. A `WRKOBJ *ALL/CSNBOWH *PGM` will tell, or when QSYSINC/H MBR(CSUCINCL) exists.

pub400 doesn't have it, maybe Holger can be persuaded?

Good reference (albeit with C code) [IBM i 7.3 Security Cryptography](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/pdf/rzajcpdf.pdf)

**Update:**

You asked for another possibility to create MD5 hashes.

There is C code on the Net that can be used for that. For Example: https://gist.github.com/creationix/4710780

That code would need to be ported to the IBM i (AS400); I personally see no big problem with that.